How can I order divisors of N so that their quotients are prime numbers?
I'm working on a problem where, given an integer N, I need to find all its divisors and print them in an order such that for any two consecutive divisors in the list, the following condition holds:
The larger divisor divided by the smaller divisor results in a prime number.
For example, for N = 12, one possible valid ordering of the divisors is:
1 2 4 12 6 3
In this sequence:

2/1=2 (prime)
4/2=2 (prime)
12/4=3 (prime)
12/6=2 (prime)
6/3=2 (prime)

If there are multiple valid solutions, any of them will suffice.
I’ve written a solution that finds all the divisors of N and sorts them, but I’m struggling to figure out how to order them based on this prime quotient condition. For instance, for N = 12, I can achieve the output 1 2 4 12 6 3, but I can't consistently generate such sequences for other values of N.
My Question:
How can I approach this problem and build the correct sequence of divisors for any integer N that satisfies the prime quotient condition? Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated!
Additional Context: I'm using C++ for the solution, and performance is a concern for larger values of N.
I’ve written a solution that finds all the divisors of N and sorts them, but I’m struggling to figure out how to order them based on this prime quotient condition. Below is a minimal example of my current code:
Input:
2
12
100

Output:
1 2 4 12 6 3
1 2 4 20 10 5 25 50 100

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define optimize() ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);
#define int long long
#define MOD 1000000007
#define endl "\n"

const int N = 1e3 + 7;

int32_t main() {
    optimize();
    
    int t; 
    cin >> t; // Read number of test cases
    while (t--) {
        vector<int> v, ans;
        int n; 
        cin >> n; // Read the integer N
        
        // Find all divisors of n
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j <= n; j += i) {
                if (j == n) {
                    v.push_back(i);
                }
            }
        }

        // Attempt to build the sequence of divisors (incomplete logic)
        // You need to implement the logic here to order the divisors based on the prime quotient condition

        // Print the divisors for now
        for (int val : v) {
            cout << val << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}


Side notes: (1) #include <bits/stdc++.h> (2) using namespace std.

Uff, brute forcing your divisor search might get expensive fast for larger N. For a first optimization, remove the inner loop and just check for n%i==0, then only run for i<=n/2.

You might do better finding the prime factorisation first and then generating the divisors in an appropriate order from it. (Successive divisors to differ by only one prime factor.)

For the actual question: A naive approach would maybe look like this: (a) For each v, check for which other v's a prime is the divisor. (b) Walk through all possible parings, trying to find one which includes all values found. This won't be an efficient algorithm by a long shot, but implement it and show what you tried here, and people might be able to help you optimize it.

We're not a leetcode/hackerrank/whatever solving service. Questions on Stack Overflow must be specific. "Give me the solution to a random competitive programming quiz" is not a specific question.

More side notes: Redefining keywords, like int, or library names, like endl, is specifically forbidden by the language standard. And isn't 1e3 + 7 the same as 1007? Oh, and optimize doesn't optimize the code, just potetially the use of cin (which isn't a bottle neck here). Where did you learn all this sh-t? Have you tried proper C++ at https://www.learncpp.com/ ?

@nick O(n/2) is the same as O(n); that wouldn't help much. It is far better to only check up to sqrt(n).

@PasserBy This looks very specific to me.

#define int is Undefined Behaviour right there.  I'm not even reading beyond that.  I tell a lie - I just saw std::int32_t main().  That's terrible!

@Unmitigated How is a spec dump specific?

@PasserBy It is clearly defined and that makes it a lot more answerable than many questions.

@Unmitigated All spec dumps are answerable in the sense that "we can write a solution", but not in the sense that "there is an identifiable knowledge gap that can be filled".

Find all the divisors. Write them as nodes of a GRAPH. Your nodes are connected if larger/smaller is prime. Your task is to traverse that graph visiting each node once.

try pass tests: https://godbolt.org/z/oW1b1PxsY

@lastchance 's comment and MBo 's deleted answer are pretty much the only reasonable answers for this problem, I think.

Think about this:  are there positive values of N for which there is no solution?

That had worried me, too, @Wyck. However, no_comment's solution would seem to work for anything that had a prime factorisation ... in other words, for any N.

You say "Below is a minimal example of my current code: input [...] output [...]", but that output isn't really from your code, is it?

Find one prime factor and its exponent. For example for N=36, find 2^2. Divide that out so you have N=9 left. Solve that recursively, so you get for example the sequence 1 3 9. Now incorporate the 2^2 by going up and down, multiplying by 2 in between:
(1 3 9) (18 6 2) (4 12 36)

Python implementation:
def divs(n, i=2):
  if n == 1:
    return [1]
  while i * i <= n:
    e = 0
    while not n % i:
      n //= i
      e += 1
    if e:
      ds = divs(n, i+1)
      result = ds[:]
      while e:
        ds.reverse()
        ds = [d * i for d in ds]
        result += ds
        e -= 1
      return result
    i += 1
  return [1, n]

print(*divs(12))
print(*divs(36))

Output (Attempt This Online!):
1 3 6 2 4 12
1 3 9 18 6 2 4 12 36

More direct bottom-up way:
def divs(n):
  result = [1]
  i = 2
  while n > 1:
    if i * i > n:
      i = n
    ds = result
    while not n % i:
      n //= i
      ds = [d * i for d in reversed(ds)]
      result += ds
    i += 1
  return result

print(*divs(12))
print(*divs(36))

Output (Attempt This Online!):
1 2 4 12 6 3
1 2 4 12 6 3 9 18 36


I like this one -- similar to a gray code construction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code

OK, but the question was tagged C++.

@Wyck But I'm no C++ person and the question is "How can I approach this problem and build the correct sequence of divisors for any integer N that satisfies the prime quotient condition? Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated!". My first part answers that. The implementations are already a bonus.

Well, I'm expanding my earlier comment with some sample code. It's more to make it work than to make it optimal, so constructive criticism welcome. For the DFS below ... well, I'm not a computer scientist.
Find all the divisors. Write them as nodes of a GRAPH. Nodes are connected if larger/smaller is prime. The graph is traversed (by DFS), visiting each node once.
(Note that in my code the nodes are the INDICES of the sorted divisors, not the divisors themselves.)
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

//======================================================================

bool isPrime( int n )                            // Test primality
{
   if ( n < 2      ) return false; 
   if ( n % 2 == 0 ) return n == 2;

   int imax = sqrt( n + 0.5 );
   for ( int i = 3; i <= imax; i += 2 )
   {
      if ( n % i == 0 ) return false;
   }
   return true;
}

//======================================================================

vector<int> getDivisors( int n )       // Find all divisors (including 1 and n)
{
   vector<int> divisors = { 1 };
   if ( n <= 1 ) return divisors;
   divisors.push_back( n );

   int imax = sqrt( n + 0.5 );         // proper divisors usually come in pairs
   for ( int i = 2; i <= imax; i++ )
   {
      if ( n % i == 0 )
      {
         divisors.push_back( i  );
         divisors.push_back( n / i );
      }
   }
   if ( imax * imax == n ) divisors.pop_back();  // don't double count

   sort( divisors.begin(), divisors.end() );
   return divisors;
}

//======================================================================

bool DFS( int test, vector<int> &sequence, const vector<vector<int>> &connections, vector<bool> &visited )
{
   if ( visited[test] ) return false;                                // already used

   sequence.push_back( test );   visited[test] = true;               // add index to sequence
   if ( sequence.size() == connections.size() ) return true;         // finished successfully

   for ( int next : connections[test] )                              // try each node connected to test
   {
      if ( DFS( next, sequence, connections, visited ) ) return true;
   }

   sequence.pop_back();   visited[test] = false;
   return false;
}

//======================================================================

int main()
{
   int N;
   cout << "Enter N: ";   cin >> N;

   vector<int> divisors = getDivisors( N );      // the collection of divisors
   int numDivisors = divisors.size();

   // Set up "connections"
   vector<vector<int>> connections(numDivisors); // for each node (an index), the indices that it is connected to
   for ( int i = 0; i < numDivisors; i++ )
   {
      for ( int j = 0; j < numDivisors; j++ )
      {
         int a = divisors[i], b = divisors[j];
         if ( a > b && a % b == 0 && isPrime( a / b ) )
         {
            connections[i].push_back( j );
            connections[j].push_back( i );
         }
      }
   }

   vector<bool> visited( N, false );             // the indices of divisors used thus far
   vector<int> sequence;                         // contains the INDICES of the divisors
   if ( DFS( 0, sequence, connections, visited ) )
   {
      for ( int e : sequence ) cout << divisors[e] << "  ";
      cout << '\n';
   }
}

Test 1:
Enter N: 12
1  2  4  12  6  3

Test 2:
Enter N: 100
1  2  4  20  10  5  25  50  100 

Test 3:
Enter N: 123456789
1  3  9  32463  10821  3607  13717421  3803  11409  34227  123456789  41152263  


"... and performance is a concern for larger values of N" - The two nested for loops in main will be pretty bad for big values. If you split the number into its prime factors then you only need to loop through the number of prime factors (and repetitions) instead of n^2. Sure, in worst case N itself can be a big prime number, then you still have to search through a lot of not matching prime numbers.

I just noticed, isPrime() can be optimized a bit to skip the lower numbers which were already tested in the prior calls, no need to test the same values again.

Thanks, @Thibe. The nested loop in the main routine scales as (number of divisors)^2 rather than n^2, so it really depends how many factors a number has. Since I had already sorted the divisors I could have cut the total loops by a factor of 2, though.
